# How to Read SMS from background task in Windows Mobile 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

Is there any way to get the SMS from Background Task in Windows 10 / Windows Phone 10 SDK.

I found this link regaring chat but im not sure :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.aspx

Kindly provide the code how to get the SMS using background task in windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It not possible to use this api unless your developer account has been specially provisioned by Microsoft.  It is noted in the top of the page you linked it

Comment: how to get that permission or authorization to use these API in order to send or receive the SMS in Windows 10 Mobile ?

Comment: talk to your local developer evangelist they might be able to help